# Execution failed for task ':react-native-music-control:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Trying to build my first app on react-native , of an existing project but unfortunately getting an error while building the app by `react-native run-android`

seems everything working fine but getting this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-music-control:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

can anybody hints me whats wrong ?

Full error log =>

```
 cd android && ./gradlew installDebug --stacktrace
```

> Configure project :realm
>   WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
>   android.enableAapt2
>   This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.

WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :react-native-music-control:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlModule.java:26: error: package androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat does not exist
>   import androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle;
>                                               ^
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:4: error: package androidx.media does not exist
>   import androidx.media.VolumeProviderCompat;
>                        ^
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
>       public static class VolumeListener extends VolumeProviderCompat {
>                                                  ^
>     symbol:   class VolumeProviderCompat
>     location: class MusicControlListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlModule.java:122: error: incompatible types: VolumeListener cannot be converted to VolumeProviderCompat
>               session.setPlaybackToRemote(volume);
>                                           ^
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlModule.java:135: error: cannot find symbol
>           nb.setStyle(new MediaStyle().setMediaSession(session.getSessionToken()));
>                           ^
>     symbol:   class MediaStyle
>     location: class MusicControlModule
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlModule.java:298: error: cannot find symbol
>           int maxVol = info.hasKey("maxVolume") ? info.getInt("maxVolume") : volume.getMaxVolume();
>                                                                                    ^
>     symbol:   method getMaxVolume()
>     location: variable volume of type VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlModule.java:299: error: cannot find symbol
>           int vol = info.hasKey("volume") ? info.getInt("volume") : volume.getCurrentVolume();
>                                                                           ^
>     symbol:   method getCurrentVolume()
>     location: variable volume of type VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlModule.java:323: error: incompatible types: VolumeListener cannot be converted to VolumeProviderCompat
>               session.setPlaybackToRemote(volume.create(null, maxVol, vol));
>                                                        ^
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlModule.java:385: error: incompatible types: VolumeListener cannot be converted to VolumeProviderCompat
>                   if(remoteVolume) session.setPlaybackToRemote(volume);
>                                                                ^
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlModule.java:390: error: incompatible types: VolumeListener cannot be converted to VolumeProviderCompat
>                       session.setPlaybackToRemote(volume);
>                                                   ^
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
>               super(changeable ? VOLUME_CONTROL_ABSOLUTE : VOLUME_CONTROL_FIXED, maxVolume, currentVolume);
>                                  ^
>     symbol:   variable VOLUME_CONTROL_ABSOLUTE
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
>               super(changeable ? VOLUME_CONTROL_ABSOLUTE : VOLUME_CONTROL_FIXED, maxVolume, currentVolume);
>                                                            ^
>     symbol:   variable VOLUME_CONTROL_FIXED
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
>               return getVolumeControl() != VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_FIXED;
>                      ^
>     symbol:   method getVolumeControl()
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
>               return getVolumeControl() != VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_FIXED;
>                                            ^
>     symbol:   variable VolumeProviderCompat
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:104: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>           @Override
>           ^
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
>               setCurrentVolume(volume);
>               ^
>     symbol:   method setCurrentVolume(int)
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:110: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>           @Override
>           ^
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
>               int maxVolume = getMaxVolume();
>                               ^
>     symbol:   method getMaxVolume()
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
>               int volume = Math.max(Math.min(getCurrentVolume() + tick, maxVolume), 0);
>                                              ^
>     symbol:   method getCurrentVolume()
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
>               setCurrentVolume(volume);
>               ^
>     symbol:   method setCurrentVolume(int)
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
>                   currentVolume = getCurrentVolume();
>                                   ^
>     symbol:   method getCurrentVolume()
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
>                   setCurrentVolume(currentVolume);
>                   ^
>     symbol:   method setCurrentVolume(Integer)
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:128: error: cannot find symbol
>               if(maxVolume == null) maxVolume = getMaxVolume();
>                                                 ^
>     symbol:   method getMaxVolume()
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   /root/SCRIPTLOCATION/Social and Sharing/codecanyon-23049351-musicengine-mobile-applications/app/node_modules/react-native-music-control/android/src/main/java/com/tanguyantoine/react/MusicControlListener.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
>               if(changeable == isChangeable() && maxVolume == getMaxVolume()) return this;
>                                                               ^
>     symbol:   method getMaxVolume()
>     location: class VolumeListener
>   Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
>   24 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-music-control:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':react-native-music-control:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:143)
      at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:40)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:24)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:46)
      at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:33)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:355)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:219)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
      at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
      at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
      at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
      at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
      at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
      at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
      at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
      at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
      at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:100)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:49)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:35)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:39)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:110)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:106)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:59)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:43)
      at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:153)
      at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:121)
      at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.kt:233)
      at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
      at

Comment: Please specify your error completely. You might need to jetify your dependencies by using `npx jetify`

Comment: This is what I'm getting on terminal .. can you please suggest me what are the code i need to include in the question?

Comment: Run `cd android && ./gradlew installDebug --stacktrace` then post result here again. This error can have many reasons.

Comment: i Have updated , can you check out ?

Comment: What react native version are you using? If you are using react native >= 0.60.0 please run command `npx jetify`

Comment: yes i am using 0.60.4 , and that will fix the errors?

Comment: Yeah! see answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Native >= 0.60 please ensure to migrate your dependencies from `android.support` to `androidx` by running `npx jetify`. Make sure that `gradle.properties` file contains following lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: m i still missing something ? its still giving me error with another line like =>* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fast-image:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.